# Firefox in AWS instance

Tags: firefox, amazon-ec2, redhat, rhel

I tried to install firefox on my redhat 8 machine.but I get
" running firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported. ($xauthority is /run/user/1001/gdm/xauthority which is owned by user.) "
Then I try it as normal user then it shows another error.
" Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
Running without a11y support! "

How to install firefox in Rhel8 (AWS EC2)? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are connecting via ssh (text mode). Firefox needs a graphical environment to run, which is not available in EC2. You will need a text-only browser.

It seems to me that you need something like WorkSpaces, not ec2 with ssh.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The minimum you also need to install with firefox would be the xauth package. This should let you run firefox both as a normal user and while su to root. As root you will need set the XAUTHORITY env variable to point to your .Xauthority file, e.g.

```
# export XAUTHORITY=/home/sbaby/.Xauthority
```

This assumes, of course, that you ssh to your server with a X11 server listening for connections. Refer to your ssh client for documentation on how to set that up.